# Handle stripe webhooks in microservice architecture

Tags: node.js, database-design, stripe-payments, webhooks

Let's say we have multiple api gateways where users make their requests, knowing that `https://apiid.globalurl.com/checkout` is where informations about the product the user is buying goes, how to handle the fact that stripe webhooks cannot be directed to the same gateway ?

My train of thought on this matter conducts me to think that the best way to do this is to have a centralized server where apis reroute users infos and that handles all webhooks but Im not a fanboy of centralized architectures..

Comment: >My train of thought on this matter conducts me to think that the best way to do this is to have a centralized server where apis reroute users info ————
that's what I would do, if it's not possible to have multiple URLs as different Stripe webhook endpoints. Be aware you can set up different URLs as https://apiid.globalurl.com/checkout?merchant=A ; https://apiid.globalurl.com/checkou?merchant=B or whatever, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about this feature but Im not sure that it can help me, i don't have merchants (i'm the merchant), and users choose their api gateway at random when they launch the nextjs app (to have sort of a sticky connection to be able to use a local redis cache on the api) so I would need webhooks to target urls dynamically.. Which is not possible from what I know